# (Done) Question about at-will firing should not have been closed

Tags: discussion

[Are employers allowed to fire at will yet employees are bound by long notice periods?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/190780/are-employers-allowed-to-fire-at-will-yet-employees-are-bound-by-long-notice-per/190782?noredirect=1#comment626932_190782)

This question should not have been closed.

It is not related to company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies. And it does not require a law degree to answer.

Anyone in the US with business knowledge in an at-will state could answer it.

I voted to reopen. You should too.

Comment: Good catch Joe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing in the question specific to the company and while I personally are not 100% sure of the answer, it does not look like a legally complicated matter. It looks exactly like something, anybody drawing up or signing a contract should know, not a case where the very specifics require a personal lawyer. So something that is very much on-topic here.

I have reopened and cleaned it up.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunate some folks like to close questions without good reasons.